# New to MySQL and having issue with joining 3 tables with roll up by Month

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show my Sales, CustomerReturns and Profit in one view.

I have done Inner Joins successfully across 2 tables, by month and successfully created views by month.  However, with 3 tables I get an error on either date or customerorders table (errors occur when playing around with code).  As the ProductID is the common column for all 3, I've put this into the ON and WHERE part.

I've played around with the code based on tutorials (I'm learning MySQL workbench independently) and research.  It seems like the code below should be working.  I can't figure out what is wrong.  Please note I have tried to do two inner joins and hasn't worked either e.g.

```
INNER JOIN supplierstockorder ON customerorders.ProductID = supplierstockorder.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID 
INNER JOIN customerreturns ON customerorders.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID
```

Can anyone help?

```
Table 1 - customerorders(CustomerOrderID varchar(255) PK,
```

Date DATE, 
CustomerID varchar(255), 
PaymentID varchar(255), 
ProductID varchar(255), 
Quantity int(20), 
OrderValue decimal(18, 2)
    Table 2 - customerreturns(ReturnID varchar(255) PK, 
CustomerID varchar(255), 
Date DATE, 
ProductID varchar(255), 
CRQuantity int(10), 
ReturnsValue int(10))
    Table 3 - supplierstockorder(SupplierStockOrderID varchar(255) PK, 
Date DATE, 
SupplierID varchar(255), 
ProductID varchar(255), 
Quantity int(10), 
CostPrice int(10), 
Vat decimal(10,2), 
SSOTotal int(10))

```
CREATE VIEW SalesProfitCrReturns AS
SELECT monthname(Date) as MonthDetails, SUM(customerorders.OrderValue) AS Sales, 
SUM(customerreturns.ReturnsValue) AS CustomerReturns, 
SUM(supplierstockorder.Quantity * supplierstockorder.CostPrice) 
- SUM(customerorders.OrderValue) 
- SUM(customerreturns.ReturnsValue) AS Profit
FROM customerorders, customerreturns
INNER JOIN supplierstockorder
ON customerorders.ProductID = supplierstockorder.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID
WHERE customerorders.ProductID = supplierstockorder.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID
GROUP BY MonthDetails with rollup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of a valid query. For further help, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

```
SELECT monthname(Date) MonthDetails
     , SUM(o.OrderValue) Sales
     , SUM(r.ReturnsValue) CustomerReturns
     , SUM(s.Quantity * s.CostPrice) - SUM(o.OrderValue) - SUM(r.ReturnsValue) Profit
  FROM customerorders o
  JOIN customerreturns r
    ON r.ProductID = o.ProductID 
  JOIN supplierstockorder s
    ON s.ProductID = o.ProductID
 GROUP 
    BY MonthDetails 
  WITH ROLLUP;
```

Note that this selects month data for all years, which is an odd request

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've edited the list of tables with columns indicating what type the columns are set as.

Comment: That's not quite (or only partially) what the link suggests

Comment: I've also tried your code and it isn't working.  Saying date ambiguous.  I only have this years data as this is all I've been in business for.

Comment: Remove the ambiguity. If date belongs to customerorders, then it's o.date. That said, if the error exists in my query, then it also exists in yours, right?

Comment: Got it sorted thank you.  I'll read the link in more detail, I had looked at the top three to change in haste.  Will ensure any queries I ask in future reflects the link.  Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: I put in o.date and it worked.  Your code is super neat, thanks for the overview of how you'd write it.  I'm going to experiment with adopting shorter code.  Never realised the level of abbreviation that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

the
INNER JOIN supplierstockorder ON customerorders.ProductID = supplierstockorder.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID 
INNER JOIN customerreturns ON customerorders.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID

has too many = comparisons
Use just
customerorders.ProductID = supplierstockorder.ProductID

and compare customerreturns.ProductID only on the other join condition

in short remove the 
= customerreturns.ProductID
from the first on condition

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM customerorders, customerreturns
INNER JOIN supplierstockorder
    ON customerorders.ProductID = supplierstockorder.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID
WHERE customerorders.ProductID = supplierstockorder.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID
```

You appear to be mixing explicit and implicit joins in the `FROM` clause. Also, the conditions in your `WHERE` and in the `ON` part of the join are not valid SQL. An equality condition involves two columns, not three (so you should have two equality conditions instead).

This should be written:

```
FROM customerorders
INNER JOIN customerreturns
    ON customerreturns.ProductID = customerorders.ProductID
INNER JOIN supplierstockorder
    ON supplierstockorder.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID
-- no WHERE clause needed
```

Finally, from your table structures, I tend to believe that the join between `customerorders` and `customerreturns`  should involve the `CustomerID`:

```
FROM customerorders
INNER JOIN customerreturns
    ON  customerreturns.ProductID = customerorders.ProductID
    AND customerreturns.CustomerID = customerorders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN supplierstockorder
    ON supplierstockorder.ProductID = customerreturns.ProductID
-- no WHERE clause needed
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Just so I'm understanding correctly, I don't need the where clause with 3 tables and I can have more than 1 set of corresponding foreign keys connecting the tables.  So if I wanted to do 4 tables, I would follow the same format as above and so on?

Comment: I've edited and run the code and I'm getting "error 1052:  COlumn 'Date' in field list is ambiguous."  I have issues with dates before.  I've set my date columns to varchar(255) for all tables and to Date for all columns and neither works.

Comment: @cmdublin: you have a column called `Date` in more than one table involved in your query. You need to *qualify* the `Date` column, ie prefix it with the table it belongs to (eg: `ècustomerorders.Date` , or `customerreturns.date`, or else).

Comment: Great thank you.  I had taken from previous code where I had used it in the one table.  It's worked now, I think.  The maths seem to be slightly off but I can double check my figures against my excel sheet.